# String is Showing letters as separate in arabic

Tags: java, android, textview, arabic, textcolor

I am using this code to search for a certain word in a string and if found, change the color:

```
String x = showdata.get(SearchResults.TAG_SHOP_SECTION_ITEM_DESC);
int positions[] = new int[100];
Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(x);  
int index = 0, i = 0;
while (index != -1)
{
    index = x.indexOf(MainActivity.SearchWord, index);
    if (index != -1)
    {      
        WordtoSpan.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), index,
                           index+MainActivity.SearchWord.length(),
                           Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        index++;
        i++;
    }
}
itemDESC.setText(WordtoSpan);
```

The code is working perfectly; however, when displaying the `wordtospan`, the colored letters seem to not be connected to the rest of the word.

#### Example:

> القدس

becomes

> الق دس

It colors the third letter, but then it seems to be separate from the rest of the word, but without the spacing.

Comment: Make sure to add your programming language as a tag. Java, right?

Comment: and is this in android?

Comment: yes, i am using eclipse java

Comment: yes i am building android applications

Comment: try add this WordtoSpan.setSpan( new TextAppearanceSpan(null, 0, 17, null, null), WordtoSpan.length(), WordtoSpan.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

Comment: i put your code before this line 

itemDESC.setText(WordtoSpan);

but still the same problem ....

Comment: I faced similar issue, so I found out that I have to manually reset the font of spanned text equal to overall font being used in the text view.

Answer (score 0):

Use SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE as start is inclusive (index).

Answer (score 0):

If you use unicode arabic letters (0x06--), recent versions of android will automatically join the letters together where required, but this is done after applying the coloring, and the colouring breaks the connection between letters.

You have to convert the Unicode Arabic letters (0x06--) into Arabic presentation B (0xFE--), and apply the connections yourself as you convert, then use set the colors on the already-connected letters

[Better-Arabic-Reshaper](https://github.com/agawish/Better-Arabic-Reshaper/)
an open source library that will return the android text in the form of Unicode,then you can apply the span colors.

please check this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17865392/android-connected-and-colored-arabic-letters) from where I got this answer.